# NSCalendar class to find the Date of a Weekday

Tags: objective-c, nscalendar

I m creating an calendar based application
for that i have used the NSCalendar class

now i want to get the Date of a perticular weekday
means if todays date is 8th dec 2012 and i pass the weekday 2 then it has to be written me the date of monday i.e. 10th Dec 2012

How to achieve this

Comment: Always the following value? If you ask for Tuesday on a Wednesday, should that give you the previous day or the one in 6 days?

Comment: No its not necessary but its only forward values no previous values are there means if today is saturday and i pass 4 as a weekday then it has to be return me next date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar`.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; // 2012-12-08 09:46:31 +0000
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setDay:2]; // your example of 2 days
date = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components
                                 toDate:date options:0];
// 2012-12-10 09:46:31 +0000
```

Comment: can you please explain how to get only date in the form of YYYY-mm-DD not with time

Comment: @infodeve1 You can use `NSDateFormatter`, but please ask a new question instead of adding a comments for those kind of things.